# Laravel pessimistic lock not working like supposed to

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm developing a little shopping website for entertainment purpose but I'm intending to apply the same code to a possible real shop website in the future.
So I have these "slots" that are meant to be bought, like a reservation slot for saving seats with numbers. 
So people will buy the slots and save the seats, but I'm facing a race condition problem, even though I'm using lockForUpdate method, I can buy more slots than I have balance for. 
My piece of code for when the user clicks "buy":

```
foreach ($tSlots as $mSlot) {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $slot = Slots::where('id', $mSlot)->lockForUpdate()->first();
    $wallet = $user::getWallet();
    $wallet->lockForUpdate();
    if (($slot->user_id === null) && ($wallet->balance >= $slot->price)) {
        $wallet->balance -= $slot->price;
        $slot->user_id = $user->id;
        if ($wallet->update() && $slot->update()) {
            $counter++;
            DB::commit();
        } else {
            DB::rollBack();
        }
    } else {
        DB::rollBack();
    }
}
```

I'm keeping track of the slots count as I will display how many slots the users has successfully bought on the view after redirection.
If i intercept the request and edit it to make, let's say, 4 requests, each buying 5 different slots, I can manage to buy more than I have balance for, and my balance turns negative. Where am I messing it up?

Comment: Hmm, can you try refreshing the $wallet **after** the lockForUpdate() call on $wallet? If it works, then I'll provide an explanation  in an answer.

Comment: Can you make sure the wallet balance changes after the `$wallet->update()`? I'd fetch the wallet once, outside the loop, and make sure the balance gets updated.

Comment: I'll try it and update You guys

Comment: @andretzermias tried checking again if the balance has changed before committing. Still can spend more than I have

Comment: @Shadow tried checking if the wallet was successfully updated and it is, still same problem. Seems like lockForUpdate is not working as the requests are all hapenning at the same time

Comment: I did not ask you to check if the wallet was updated. I asked you to refresh the $wallet variable in php after the locking call. The problem I suspect is that you read the wallet and therefore its balance before trying to lock it. If the previous transaction was not commited yet, then the previous balance will be read into php.

Comment: Then you calculate the balance within the php code - which again is not visible on the database level. Then you update the modified balance back to the database. Actually, the balance update should be done on the database level calculating the new balance on the fly and rejecting it, if you do not have enough balance. If you have repeatable read isolation mode, then a simple refresh may not be enough.

Comment: @Shadow But doesn't locking the table avoid it to be read before the previous transaction commits?

Comment: 1. You are not locking any table, only certain rows. 2. Mysql manual is a bit vague, but in my experience, under the default repeatable read isolation mode the exclusive locks do not prevent a regular, non-locking read. You should change the first read of the wallet into a locking one, then it will work.

Comment: @Shadow changed it to  ```$wallet = Wallets::where('user_id', $user->id)->lockForUpdate()->first();``` on the first read. Still hapening

Comment: Then you need to check on database level what locks are created and when. I do not really know what the above php call will translate into in mysql.

Comment: Alright, I'll see what I can do. in the meanwhile I wait for answers