# Laravel pessimistic locking cannot prevent SELECT on uncommitted row in multiple duplicate request

Tags: mysql, laravel, locking, innodb

I tried to prevent **unintentional duplicate request** from changing my model for the second time when double clicking a button. I do the following.

```php
Log::debug('Begin transaction');
DB::beginTransaction();

$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$pdo->exec('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE');

try {
    $user = \App\User::sharedLock()->find($id);
    Log::debug('Select user: ' . pickfield($user));

    if ($user->checkout) {
        Log::debug('Already checked out, rollback');
        DB::rollback();

        return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Already checked out');
    }

    Log::debug('Changing checkout..');
    $user->checkout = new \DateTime($request->input('checkout'));

    Log::debug('Saving checkout: ' . pickfield($user));
    $user->save();

    Log::debug('Commit!');
    DB::commit();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    Log::debug('Error, rollback!');
    DB::rollback();
}
```

Transactions still run thus overlap to each other and make SELECT statement retrieve inconsistent model even after I put a shared lock with serializable isolation.

```
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: Begin transaction
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: Begin transaction
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: Select user: {"id":3225,"checkout":null}
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: Changing checkout..
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: Saving checkout: {"id":3225,"checkout":{"date":"2019-05-17 01:02:45.428000","timezone_type":2,"timezone":"Z"}}
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: On model updating: {}
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.INFO: Sending email to user1@example.com
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: Begin transaction
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: Select user: {"id":3225,"checkout":null}
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: Changing checkout..
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: Saving checkout: {"id":3225,"checkout":{"date":"2019-05-17 01:02:45.604000","timezone_type":2,"timezone":"Z"}}
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.DEBUG: On model updating: {}
[2019-05-17 01:02:45] local.INFO: Sending email to user1@example.com
[2019-05-17 01:03:00] local.DEBUG: Commit!
[2019-05-17 01:03:00] local.DEBUG: Error, rollback!
```

I though my code already guarantee to prevent `SELECT` query executed in the middle of another transaction. I use InnoDB.

Related, no solution: [Laravel pessimistic lock not working like supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52806969/laravel-pessimistic-lock-not-working-like-supposed-to)

Any explanation or solution?

Comment: Are you using the "lazy" method?  Or aggressive?

Comment: Can you please show us the generated SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! I was confused.

It was my locking type that was incorrect. It should be `lockForUpdate`.

> A "for update" lock prevents the rows from being modified or from being selected with another shared lock.

While **a shared lock**,

> A shared lock prevents the selected rows from being modified until
>   your transaction commits.

I've tested both but with MyISAM engine and doesn't work at all that's why I was confused.

Comment: MyISAM doesn't support transactions, so any lock you create is released as soon as the SELECT finishes.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is by disabling the button before hitting the endpoint which is important even if you managed to solve this issue as you shouldn't allow (as much as you can) sending duplicate requests at all.

Comment: Thanks, but cumbersome when your button is all over the place.